# multidimensional array merge into one array if key is same without using nested loop

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-merge

```
    [
      {
        "status": true,
        "data": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Algeria",
            "country_code": "DZ",
            "regions": [
              {
                "id": 2,
                "country_id": 2,
                "region_code": "RG01",
                "depots": [
                  {
                    "id": 5,
                    "region_id": 2,
                    "depot_code": "DP04",
                    "depot_name": "North Depot",
                    "area": [
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "depot_id": 5,
                        "area_code": "AR1",
                        "area_name": "Area-1"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 2,
                        "depot_id": 5,
                        "area_code": "AR2",
                        "area_name": "Area-2"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 6,
                    "region_id": 2,
                    "depot_code": "DP06",
                    "depot_name": "east Depot",
                    "area": [
                      {
                        "id": 3,
                        "depot_id": 6,
                        "area_code": "AR3",
                        "area_name": "Area-3"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "country_id": 2,
                "region_code": "RG02",
                "depots": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

i want to merge area into single array like

```
    "area": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "depot_id": 5,
        "area_code": "AR1",
        "area_name": "Area-1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "depot_id": 5,
        "area_code": "AR2",
        "area_name": "Area-2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "depot_id": 6,
        "area_code": "AR3",
        "area_name": "Area-3"
      }
    ]
```

i don't want to use multiple foreach.
thanks in advance.

Comment: make a collection from your array, and then use merge method on that new created collection, you will get the idea. See laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-merge

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ It's not like this. I tried a full day to solve this problem. But I'm tired now. And also resolved the issue through nested loops.But after seeing the response of APIs. I changed my mind. Because each API has different responses. So I want to make a common function for that.I need some help for resolve this problem.thats all.

Comment: Ok, no problem, it was just a suggestion so you have a better chance of getting an answer. I see that someone already wrote an answer. Good luck!

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I'll keep it in my mind next time thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to recursively iterate of all your structure and extract only data you need (by key). I assume $data has your original data structure and within $result you will get array of area:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$result = [];
foreach ($it as $k => $v) {
    if ($k === 'area') {
        $result = array_merge($result, $v);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I would not overcomplicate things, loop through you data structure. Add all areas to a collection. Prepare your data structure and i added a check to secure there is no duplicates with `unique()`.

```
$data = 'your-data';
$areas = collect();

foreach($data->data as $country) {
    foreach($country->regions as $region) {
        foreach ($region->depots as $depot) {
            $areas->concat($depot->area);
        }
    } 
}

$result = ['area' => $areas->unique('id')->all()];
```